# To create a heatmap in output apriori

Tags: apriori, arules

I would like also to create a data.frame with the rules in the row and the column items filled in according to 1 or 0.
Example:

```
            A   B   C   D
A + B + C   1   1   1   0
A + D + C   1   0   1   1
```

Any suggestions? The idea is to create a heatmap.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as(x, "matrix")` converts an `itemMatrix` into a logical matrix. Example:

```
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
  parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
as(items(rules), "matrix")
```

`items()` extracts the LHS and RHS of the rule as a single `itemMatrix`.

You can convert the matrix into a data.frame and change it from logical to 0-1 (using `storage.mode()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for!